# How to initiate a process only once in .NET Core Background service ExecuteAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, backgroundworker, background-service

We have a background service that listens for events coming in different message queues. The service was created using VS template for worker service, and implements `BackgroundService`.

I need to make sure the queue listener is invoked **only once** in the `ExecuteAsync` method. But the following code will keep on calling `ListenToQueue` method indefinitely.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    ListenToQueue(queue1);
    ListenToQueue(queue2);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the while loop? It's not needed in your scenario

Comment: Yes the while loop is not there in our code, I added it here to mimic the default worker template. Let me remove it from here to avoid confusion.

Comment: How do you know it’s being called multiple times?

Comment: I need a little more information.  It sounds like you want the line "ListenToQueue(queue1)" to only execute one time regardless of how many times ExecuteAsync is called?

Comment: There is a log statement before calling the ListenToQueue method. That log statement is appearing in logs often/random times, from several times a minute, to once every few minutes.

Comment: @jrandomuser I need ListenToQueue to be executed only once when the application starts. It basically starts listening to the message queue by creating a connection/session/subscriber.

Comment: If you want to call some method when the application started , I suggest you could consider using the IHostApplicationLifetime Events.  Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ihostapplicationlifetime).

Comment: Does it have to be a worker process that implements `BackgroundService`? Can't it be a simple console application?

Comment: I don't get your points, the asp.net core application could be built for the console application.

Comment: @BrandoZhang ended up using IHostApplicationLifetime like you suggested and it's just what I wanted.

Comment: I am glad to help you, I will generate an answer based on previous comment, if you feel the answer help you, please mark it as answer, this will help other folks who faces the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call some method when the application started , I suggest you could consider using the IHostApplicationLifetime Events. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ihostapplicationlifetime).

```
public class HostApplicationLifetimeEventsHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

    public HostApplicationLifetimeEventsHostedService(
        IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
        => _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => Task.CompletedTask;

    private void OnStarted()
    {
        // ...
    }

    private void OnStopping()
    {
        // ...
    }

    private void OnStopped()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```